# Draw Shapes Example from Core Java not appearing in frame

Tags: java, swing, graphics, shapes

I was reading Core Java and encountered this code snippet:

```
package draw;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.geom.*;
import javax.swing.*;
public class DrawTest 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
{
    public void run()
    {
        JFrame frame = new DrawFrame();
    frame.setTitle("DrawTest");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    }
});
}
}

class DrawFrame extends JFrame
{
    public DrawFrame()
    {
    add(new DrawComponent());
    pack();
    }
}

class DrawComponent extends JComponent
{
    private static final int DEFAULT_WIDTH = 400;
    private static final int DEFAULT_HEIGHT = 400;

    public void paintCompent(Graphics g)
    {
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

    // draw a rectangle
    double leftX = 100;
    double topY = 100;
    double width = 200;
    double height = 150;

    Rectangle2D rect = new Rectangle2D.Double(leftX, topY, width, height);
    g2.draw(rect);
    // draw the enclosed ellipse
    Ellipse2D ellipse = new Ellipse2D.Double();
    ellipse.setFrame(rect);
    g2.draw(ellipse);

    // draw a diagonal line
    g2.draw(new Line2D.Double(leftX, topY, leftX + width, topY + height));

    // draw a circle with the same center
    double centerX = rect.getCenterX();
    double centerY = rect.getCenterY();
    double radius = 150;
    Ellipse2D circle = new Ellipse2D.Double();
    circle.setFrameFromCenter(centerX, centerY, centerX + radius, centerY + radius);
    g2.draw(circle);
    }

    public Dimension getPreferredSize()
    {
        return new Dimension(DEFAULT_WIDTH, DEFAULT_HEIGHT);
    }
}
```

I tried this code on Eclipse, it did run but, instead of rectangles, ellipse, diagonal lines and circle, there appeared nothing in the frame. I double-checked the code against the book, there was no typo. What is wrong?

Comment: Method "paintCompent" needs to be changed as paintComponent

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a spelling mistake...

```
public void paintCompent(Graphics g) {
```

should be

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
```

This is why you should use the `@Override` annotation, as it will give you a compile time error when you try to override a method that doesn't exist within the parent hierarcy.

You should also be calling `super.paintComponent(g);`  before performing any custom painting

Comment: Oh, we're all mad here.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch You don't need to be, but it sure does make life more interesting ;)

Comment: Actually, the rest of the quote is: "How do you know I'm mad?" said Alice. "You must be," said the Cat, "or you wouldn't have come here." - Lewis Carroll